# Make NHibernate Live Entirely Within DataAccess Project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to get Fluent NHibernate configured for the first time.  You'll have to excuse me as I'm new to it.

How do I make NHibernate, all of its DLLs and config XML live within a class library project?  My solution is a classic three-tier app with the web layer (MVC3) referencing a business layer (Class Library) referencing a data access layer (Class Library).  There are no direct references from the web layer to the data access layer.

I'm running into all kinds of issues such as NHibernate trying to find the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in the root /bin directory, errors saying it cannot locate `NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle` or one of its dependencies, and some random others as I tinker with things.  Everything works fine when I reference all of the NHibernate DLLs in the MVC project as well as the DataAccess project and put the `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the MVC project, but both of these seem like a bad idea to me.

There simply must be an easy way to do this!

Can someone point me to a sample project that configures NHibernate in this manner?

Comment: I have the exact same setup that you do.  I read on NHibernate Getting Started posts say to just copy the NHibernate.dll to the bin folder of the UI project so it can find those references.  I did, and I don't like that it's there, but it was the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: @DavidAndroidDev Ugh.  Very unfortunate.  Hopefully someone else will chime in with some crafty way!

Comment: Fact is, your application needs these libraries, so you must provide them. You don't have to reference them in your web project, but they have to be present and accessible for the web application nonetheless. You could for instance use a script for deployment that copies the additional dependencies to your deployment bin folder. You could probably also install the additional dependencies in the GAC of the web server. (Info on required permissions for GAC deployment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwzs111e.aspx)

Comment: @GarlandGreene It seems strange that it wouldn't suffice to reference these DLLs from the DataAccess project.  Do you know why the MVC application must reference them?

Comment: i didn't state that the web project has to reference the dependencies. The application just has to be able to locate them as soon as it starts using them through the data access layer.

Comment: @GarlandGreene I have the DLL (the NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle) referenced in the DataAccess project's References with CopyLocal set to true.  Yet, all of the DLLs *except this one* end up within the MVC project's BIN directory on build.  Any clue as to why this one would be excluded and wouldn't just get placed in the root /bin via this reference?

Comment: @GarlandGreene Seems VisualStudio attempts to be smart and doesn't copy DLLs that aren't explicitly being used by your code.  Lovely.  Thanks, VS.  Ideas on getting around that?

Comment: yes, VS isn't acting really smart there. The DLL will be in the bin directory of your data access project, but VS doesn't copy it over to a project that references the data access project.

Comment: Only thing i can think of is doing a post build on the DataAccess project to copy out from the bin folder to the MVC project...Ill post the full script as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the answer to my own question.  The reason the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file had to live within the web directory was because of how I was referencing it.  Instead of referring to it by name, you instead have to embed the resource and refer to it in a *fully qualified* manner:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().Configure(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "MyDataAccessApp.hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Second, the necessary NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle DLL wasn't being put into the root BIN folder because of Visual Studio erroneously thinking that it is not needed (because there are no explicit code references to it).  So, this problem can be solved in three ways that I found:

- Add a line of code newing up an object in the Castle namespace (not recommended, but it works...)
- Add a build script to copy the necessary DLL into the BIN. (DavidAndroidDev's solution should work)
- Finally, the route that I went, is to add the DLL reference to your MVC project as well and just call it a day.

Hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in the comment, the "best" way to automate this is a post build script that runs after the build on the DataLayer project.

I would put

```
copy $(TargetDir)\NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll $(SolutionDir)\REL_PATH_TO_MVC_PROJECT\bin
```

You could also work this as a prebuild to MVC instead.

Comment: +1 I had to do something similar to reliably get NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle added to the proper directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) to merge all of the NHibernate components into your data access assembly, giving you just a single library to reference.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran **ILDasm** on NHibernate.dll (v.2.1.2) from the Visual Studio Command Prompt, and there is no AssemblyRef for NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.

So the problem is not Visual Studio per se, the problem is that the Nhibernate DLL does not directly reference a dependent assembly.  I vaguely remember reading that this is because the Castle DLLs are only needed when using lazy loading, but this has caused problems for many people, myself included.

I ended up using a post build script, as suggested by DavidAndroidDev.  Ugly, but it works.

Note that the latest version of NH - v3.2 - has a built in byte code provider, and does not require the Castle DLLs anymore.

However, I recently upgraded directly from NH 2.1.2 / FNH 1.0 to NH 3.2 / FNH 1.3 (pre-release), and have found several breaking changes in both components.  So for a new FNH user, it's probably better to stay with an older version.